# text mesh pro text isnt going in text slot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So apparently, i was working on my games dialogue and of course, i have to put the text in the text slot for my code. I tried putting it in the slot but it didnt work. I tried changing the "Text" to "TextMesh" but still, didnt work.

[image]

this is my code that i tried for the game.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Goose : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject dialoguePanel;
   public TextMesh dialogueText;
   public string[] dialogue;
   private int index;

   public float wordSpeed;
   public bool playerIsClose;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && playerIsClose)
        {
            if(dialoguePanel.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                zeroText();
            }
            else
            {
                dialoguePanel.SetActive(true);
                StartCoroutine(Typing());
            }
        }
    }



    public void zeroText()
    {
        dialogueText.text = "";
        index = 0;
        dialoguePanel.SetActive(false);
    }


IEnumerator Typing()
{
    foreach(char letter in dialogue[index].ToCharArray())
    {
        dialogueText.text += letter;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(wordSpeed);
    }
}

public void NextLine()
{
    if(index < dialogue.Length - 1)
    {
        index++;
        dialogueText.text = "";
        StartCoroutine(Typing());
    }
    else
    {
        zeroText();
    }
}


    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerIsClose = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerIsClose = false;
            zeroText();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not `unityscript`. Unityscript got deprecated years ago and is obsolete. Please tag your question properly with the tag `unity3d` instead.

Comment: `TextMesh` != `TextMeshProUGUI` ...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `public TMP_Text dialogueText`

Comment: where do i put it?

Comment: Replace your `public TextMesh dialogueText;` variable with `public TMP_Text dialogueText;` You might need to do some slight code adjustments but in the end you will be able to drag and drop your text field into the slot